# How can I add Markdown syntax highligting to Pluma in 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, syntax-highlighting, pluma

I'm using Pluma on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS and I see that it does not support syntax highlighting for Markdown lightweight markup language.

But I know that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (and newer versions) have this highlighting pre-installed.

How can I add Markdown syntax highligting to Pluma in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but with one thing to be considered: all current Ubuntu versions already have `markdown.lang` file in the repositories as a part of [`libgtksourceview-3.0-common`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=markdown.lang) package, but in Ubuntu 16.04 Pluma uses `libgtksourceview2.0-0` as [a dependency](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/pluma).

So here we need to install the `libgtksourceview-3.0-common` package with

```
sudo apt-get install libgtksourceview-3.0-common
```

and then copy `markdown.lang` file manually to current user configuration folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/
cd ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/
cp /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/markdown.lang .
```

then restart Pluma and enjoy:

> [image: Markdown is highlighted in Pluma 1.12.2]

---

Notes:

1. and any other `lang`-file may be installed with similar way. The full list is the following: *actionscript, ansforth94, automake, bennugd, bluespec, cobol, cpphdr, csv, gdb-log, genie, go, idl-exelis, imagej, jade, j, json, julia, lex, llvm, markdown, matlab, mediawiki, meson, modelica, mxml, netrexx, objj, opencl, pig, protobuf, puppet, python3, rst, rust, scala, scilab, sml, sweave, systemverilog, thrift, yaml*.
2. this approach gives free bonus - the Meld merge diff tool will use the same `lang`-files to highlight syntax.

Comment: i would rather add it system wide for all users and use a symlink: `sudo ln -i -s /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/markdown.lang /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/markdown.lang` as described here: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-pluma/56